# Diskless Problem Network

Tags: networking, nfs, pxe

I'm new on the askubuntu.com and I want to expose my problem. I'm sorry for my poor english.

I have a big project to implement a big cluster calculations. I'm stuck at a part, let me explain.

The context is:
- 6 diskless servers that must start over the network to the front-end server.
- 1 front end server containing a previously created image on a node server (temporarily installed hard disk before copying it to the front).

I have used that tutorials :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto

http://www.serenux.com/2011/04/howto-create-a-diskless-workstation-that-boots-from-pxe-using-ubuntu/

The testing phase is as follows:
The first node server used for backup communicated well NFS when copying files vmlinuz and initrd. So I kept the original wiring. At startup, the DHCP server responds now The TFTP server also works and startup begins.

A problem occurs during the startup of cores.
The problem is divided into 2 parts:
On the one hand in my file /tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default I leave as shown in the tutorial the following line:

```
APPEND root=/dev/nfs initrd=initrd.img-Version nfsroot=192.168.2.1:/nfsroot ip=dhcp rw
```

Messages appear about network interfaces, indicating that no response on each interfaces.

So I decided to change the /tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default to set a static IP:

```
APPEND root=/dev/nfs initrd=initrd.img-MaVersion nfsroot=192.168.2.1:/nfsroot ip=192.168.2.3:192.168.2.1::255.255.255.0:ubuntuNoeud:eth0:static rw
```

I do not have the previous messages. However I am stuck again :

```
Begin : Running /scripts/nfs-premount … done
[   66.950701] random : nonblocking pool is initialized
connect : Connection timed out
```

I suppose there is a connection problem with the NFS. I have checked first step where you have to specify a module for the NIC. So I said "isb" I was inspired by your internal documentation to the company and the following command "lsmod".

It's strange, when I put the argument "ip=dhcp" server that the node can recover a PXE boot the IP but not to this second point. As if faith launched the core, the server no longer communicating and isolated.

My configuration :

- The firewall IFW has down.

---

```
# /nfsroot/etc/network/interfaces

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
```

---

```
# /etc/exports

# /etc/exports: the access control list for filesystems which may be exported
#       to NFS clients.  See exports(5).
#
# Example for NFSv2 and NFSv3:
# /srv/homes       hostname1(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)    hostname2(ro,sync,no_subtree_check)
#
# Example for NFSv4:
# /srv/nfs4        gss/krb5i(rw,sync,fsid=0,crossmnt,no_subtree_check)
# /srv/nfs4/homes  gss/krb5i(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
#
/nfsroot    192.168.2.0/24(rw,no_root_squash,async,insecure,no_subtree_check)
```

---

```
# /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

allow booting;
allow bootp;

subnet 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 192.168.2.10 192.168.2.253;
    option broadcast-address 192.168.2.255;

    next-server 192.168.2.1;
    filename "/pxelinux.0"; 
}
```

---

```
# /tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default

DEFAULT linux
LABEL linux
KERNEL vmlinuz-3.13.0-77-generic
APPEND root=/dev/nfs initrd=initrd.img-3.13.0-77-generic    nfsroot=192.168.2.1:/nfsroot    ip=192.168.2.3:192.168.2.1::255.255.255.0:ubuntuNoeud:eth0:static rw live-netdev=eth0 ethdevice-timeout=10
```

---

```
# /etc/default/tftpd-hpa

# /etc/default/tftpd-hpa
TFTP_USERNAME="tftp"
#TFTP_DIRECTORY="/var/lib/tftpboot"
TFTP_DIRECTORY="/tftpboot"
TFTP_ADDRESS="[::]:69"
TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure -c"
RUN_DAEMON="yes"
OPTIONS="-l -s /tftpboot"
```

Thank !

Bebo,

Comment: If you could drop to shell and check for network interfaces names, It is possible that the kernel is giving it a different name.